# Javascript How To : hide the browser popup for onBeforeUnload and display custom popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onbeforeunload

I am building a MMO which has a tutorial in it.

When the user tries to navigate away from the tutorial or close the tab/browser while on the tutorial, I need to show a custom popup which has a options as to why the person is quitting the tutorial.

I am familiar with the `onbeforeunload` event but my requirement is to display the custom popup instead of the browser default popup as it can't be customized other than changing the text message.

Is there any way I can hide the browser popup and show my custom popup instead.

Comment: Where is the browser popup coming from if not a programmed JavaScript alert?

Comment: `onbeforeunload` invokes the browsre popup
like this

`window.onbeforeunload = function(event) 
    {
     var surveyText = "Please take a few moments to let us know why you want to quit the tutorial by clicking on the 'Stay on page' button below";
     return surveyText;
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I'd really suggest you use jQuery UI for this. It'll make your life much easier and has modal dialogs built into the API. See here: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal</strike>

OK, what I said before was totally wrong. Must have been tired.

You can't override the `onbeforeunload` because of the way it fires in the DOM. This is a good SO explaining it.

[How can I override the OnBeforeUnload dialog and replace it with my own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own)

Comment: I don't think that this will work for browser events.I am pretty sure that this will work for other `javascript events` like clicking a link on the page,etc,but are you sure that this will work for a `browser event`.It would be great if you could share a working demo or a JSFiddle for this one.

Comment: What I'm saying is you can open whatever you want to present in a modal dialog and disable the buttons for X amount of seconds.

Comment: I am not sure if I follow you.How would you disable the close button.

Comment: There is a .button("disable") API in jQuery.

Comment: Again, that doesn't apply to browser close button!

Comment: Sure it does. You just couple it up with the .unload() handler.

Comment: I can but I'm in bed on my iPad now.  If you still don't have it by the time I wake up I'll do one on there.

Comment: That would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Just a quick idea.  

`$(window).unload(function() {
  $("#stop-close").dialog("open");
});`

Comment: @harsha: See my updated solution. Seems you where right after all. :(

Comment: Thanks for the link.Will accept this as the answer :-)
Hoping someday, browsers will have facilitate custom popups on browser events.

Comment: Is there another alternative so I can show my modal/popup without showing browser's alert?